# Add metadata to large number of files in SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, metadata

We're migrating a large number of files from a document management system into SharePoint online.  We have important metadata associated with a good number of the files.  The export process renames the files as nnnnn_yyyyy_oldfilename with nnnnn being a cabinet number and yyyyy being a folder number.  It also creates a file that associates all existing metadata by these two pieces of information.  Is it practical to script renaming the files back to their original names while storing the two pieces of information in new custom metadata fields (cabinet, ofolder) for each file?  If we can save those pieces of information, we'll then be able to use a similar script to push the saved information into other custom metadata fields later on.